# Ggplot de um Data.frame em gráficos separados

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Tenho esse data.frame:

```
> df
           ind    m         X1       X2
1   2015-12-21   21     0.1431529 0.1426365
2   2015-12-21   42     0.1403679 0.1443714
3   2015-12-21   63     0.1467133 0.1466899
4   2015-12-21   84     0.1513388 0.1485589
5   2015-12-21  105     0.1543437 0.1504224
6   2015-12-21  126     0.1563804 0.1521211
7   2015-12-21  147     0.1578400 0.1540595
8   2015-12-21  168     0.1589353 0.1557416
9   2015-12-21  189     0.1597872 0.1570508
10  2015-12-21  210     0.1604689 0.1581820
11  2015-12-21  231     0.1610265 0.1591167
12  2015-12-21  252     0.1614913 0.1598340
13  2015-12-21  273     0.1618845 0.1609237
14  2015-12-21  294     0.1622215 0.1620525
15  2015-12-21  315     0.1625137 0.1630830
16  2015-12-21  336     0.1627693 0.1638686
17  2015-12-21  357     0.1629948 0.1645696
18  2015-12-21  378     0.1631953 0.1651773
19  2015-12-21  399     0.1633746 0.1656657
20  2015-12-21  420     0.1635361 0.1660847
21  2015-12-21  441     0.1636821 0.1664921
22  2015-12-21  462     0.1638149 0.1667551
23  2015-12-21  483     0.1639361 0.1669551
24  2015-12-21  504     0.1640473 0.1671720
25  2015-12-21  525     0.1641495 0.1673453
26  2015-12-21  546     0.1642439 0.1675000
27  2015-12-21  567     0.1643313 0.1676821
28  2015-12-21  588     0.1644124 0.1679642
29  2015-12-21  609     0.1644880 0.1681595
30  2015-12-21  630     0.1645585 0.1683756
31  2015-12-21  651     0.1646244 0.1684000
32  2015-12-21  672     0.1646863 0.1684000
33  2015-12-21  693     0.1647444 0.1683297
34  2015-12-21  714     0.1647990 0.1683000
35  2015-12-21  735     0.1648506 0.1683000
36  2015-12-21  756     0.1648993 0.1683000
37  2015-12-21  777     0.1649453 0.1682282
38  2015-12-21  798     0.1649890 0.1681198
39  2015-12-21  819     0.1650304 0.1680000
40  2015-12-21  840     0.1650697 0.1680000
41  2015-12-21  861     0.1651071 0.1678616
42  2015-12-21  882     0.1651427 0.1677899
43  2015-12-21  903     0.1651767 0.1676472
44  2015-12-21  924     0.1652091 0.1675540
45  2015-12-21  945     0.1652401 0.1674180
46  2015-12-21  966     0.1652697 0.1673603
47  2015-12-21  987     0.1652981 0.1672298
48  2015-12-21 1008     0.1653253 0.1671140
49  2015-12-21 1029     0.1653514 0.1669603
50  2015-12-21 1050     0.1653764 0.1668124
51  2015-12-21 1071     0.1654005 0.1667165
52  2015-12-21 1092     0.1654236 0.1665495
53  2015-12-21 1113     0.1654459 0.1664299
54  2015-12-21 1134     0.1654673 0.1663000
55  2015-12-21 1155     0.1654879 0.1662152
56  2015-12-21 1176     0.1655079 0.1661180
57  2015-12-21 1197     0.1655271 0.1660165
58  2015-12-21 1218     0.1655456 0.1659519
59  2015-12-21 1239     0.1655636 0.1657849
60  2015-12-21 1260     0.1655809 0.1657073
61  2015-12-21 1281     0.1655976 0.1655520
62  2015-12-21 1302     0.1656139 0.1654799
63  2015-12-21 1323     0.1656296 0.1653000
64  2015-12-21 1344     0.1656448 0.1652425
65  2015-12-21 1365     0.1656595 0.1651239
66  2015-12-21 1386     0.1656738 0.1650000
67  2015-12-21 1407     0.1656877 0.1648901
68  2015-12-21 1428     0.1657012 0.1648000
69  2015-12-21 1449     0.1657142 0.1647000
70  2015-12-21 1470     0.1657269 0.1646000
71  2015-12-21 1491     0.1657393 0.1644705
72  2015-12-21 1512     0.1657513 0.1644032
73  2015-12-21 1533     0.1657630 0.1644480
74  2015-12-21 1554     0.1657743 0.1645000
75  2015-12-21 1575     0.1657854 0.1645000
76  2015-12-21 1596     0.1657961 0.1646000
77  2015-12-21 1617     0.1658066 0.1646399
78  2015-12-21 1638     0.1658168 0.1647000
79  2015-12-21 1659     0.1658268 0.1647000
80  2015-12-21 1680     0.1658365 0.1647549
81  2015-12-21 1701     0.1658460 0.1648000
82  2015-12-21 1722     0.1658552 0.1648000
83  2015-12-21 1743     0.1658642 0.1648368
84  2015-12-21 1764     0.1658730 0.1649000
85  2015-12-21 1785     0.1658816 0.1649000
86  2015-12-21 1806     0.1658900 0.1648442
87  2015-12-21 1827     0.1658982 0.1648000
88  2015-12-21 1848     0.1659062 0.1648000
89  2015-12-21 1869     0.1659140 0.1647316
90  2015-12-21 1890     0.1659217 0.1647000
91  2015-12-21 1911     0.1659292 0.1647000
92  2015-12-21 1932     0.1659365 0.1646602
93  2015-12-21 1953     0.1659437 0.1646000
94  2015-12-21 1974     0.1659507 0.1646000
95  2015-12-21 1995     0.1659576 0.1646000
96  2015-12-21 2016     0.1659643 0.1645899
97  2015-12-21 2037     0.1659709 0.1645198
98  2015-12-21 2058     0.1659773 0.1645000
99  2015-12-21 2079     0.1659837 0.1645000
100 2015-12-21 2100     0.1659899 0.1645000
101 2015-12-21 2121     0.1659959 0.1644496
102 2015-12-21 2142     0.1660019 0.1644000
103 2015-12-21 2163     0.1660077 0.1644000
104 2015-12-21 2184     0.1660134 0.1643750
105 2015-12-21 2205     0.1660191 0.1643380
106 2015-12-21 2226     0.1660246 0.1643017
107 2015-12-21 2247     0.1660300 0.1643000
108 2015-12-21 2268     0.1660353 0.1642968
109 2015-12-21 2289     0.1660405 0.1642309
110 2015-12-21 2310     0.1660456 0.1641806
111 2015-12-21 2331     0.1660506 0.1641442
112 2015-12-21 2352     0.1660556 0.1641084
113 2015-12-21 2373     0.1660604 0.1641000
114 2015-12-21 2394     0.1660652 0.1640847
115 2015-12-21 2415     0.1660699 0.1640210
116 2015-12-21 2436     0.1660745 0.1639732
117 2015-12-21 2457     0.1660790 0.1639335
118 2015-12-21 2478     0.1660834 0.1639000
119 2015-12-21 2499     0.1660878 0.1638653
120 2015-12-21 2520     0.1660921 0.1638000
```

Observe que na primeira coluna só tenho uma data.
Para essa data quero plotar um gráfico onde o eixo x é a coluna "m" e o eixo x contem as colunas X1 e X2.

Para isso uso esse código:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df$m, y=df$X2, colour=ind))+ 
  xlab('m') + ylab('Taxas')+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position='top') +
  ggtitle('.')+ 
  geom_point()+ geom_line()+
  geom_point(aes(x=df$m,y = df$X1,colour=ind)) +
  geom_point(y = df$X1, color="black")+
  geom_line(y = df$X1, color="blue")+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12,colour="black"),axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45))
```

O meu problema surge quando tenho mais de uma data. Por exemplo, quando tenho duas datas quero plotar 2 gráficos separados. 
Queria só uma dica:

Segue o df com duas datas:

```
          ind    m        X1        X2
1   2015-12-21   21 0.1431529 0.1426365
2   2015-12-21   42 0.1403679 0.1443714
3   2015-12-21   63 0.1467133 0.1466899
4   2015-12-21   84 0.1513388 0.1485589
5   2015-12-21  105 0.1543437 0.1504224
6   2015-12-21  126 0.1563804 0.1521211
7   2015-12-21  147 0.1578400 0.1540595
8   2015-12-21  168 0.1589353 0.1557416
9   2015-12-21  189 0.1597872 0.1570508
10  2015-12-21  210 0.1604689 0.1581820
11  2015-12-21  231 0.1610265 0.1591167
12  2015-12-21  252 0.1614913 0.1598340
13  2015-12-21  273 0.1618845 0.1609237
14  2015-12-21  294 0.1622215 0.1620525
15  2015-12-21  315 0.1625137 0.1630830
16  2015-12-21  336 0.1627693 0.1638686
17  2015-12-21  357 0.1629948 0.1645696
18  2015-12-21  378 0.1631953 0.1651773
19  2015-12-21  399 0.1633746 0.1656657
20  2015-12-21  420 0.1635361 0.1660847
21  2015-12-21  441 0.1636821 0.1664921
22  2015-12-21  462 0.1638149 0.1667551
23  2015-12-21  483 0.1639361 0.1669551
24  2015-12-21  504 0.1640473 0.1671720
25  2015-12-21  525 0.1641495 0.1673453
26  2015-12-21  546 0.1642439 0.1675000
27  2015-12-21  567 0.1643313 0.1676821
28  2015-12-21  588 0.1644124 0.1679642
29  2015-12-21  609 0.1644880 0.1681595
30  2015-12-21  630 0.1645585 0.1683756
31  2015-12-21  651 0.1646244 0.1684000
32  2015-12-21  672 0.1646863 0.1684000
33  2015-12-21  693 0.1647444 0.1683297
34  2015-12-21  714 0.1647990 0.1683000
35  2015-12-21  735 0.1648506 0.1683000
36  2015-12-21  756 0.1648993 0.1683000
37  2015-12-21  777 0.1649453 0.1682282
38  2015-12-21  798 0.1649890 0.1681198
39  2015-12-21  819 0.1650304 0.1680000
40  2015-12-21  840 0.1650697 0.1680000
41  2015-12-21  861 0.1651071 0.1678616
42  2015-12-21  882 0.1651427 0.1677899
43  2015-12-21  903 0.1651767 0.1676472
44  2015-12-21  924 0.1652091 0.1675540
45  2015-12-21  945 0.1652401 0.1674180
46  2015-12-21  966 0.1652697 0.1673603
47  2015-12-21  987 0.1652981 0.1672298
48  2015-12-21 1008 0.1653253 0.1671140
49  2015-12-21 1029 0.1653514 0.1669603
50  2015-12-21 1050 0.1653764 0.1668124
51  2015-12-21 1071 0.1654005 0.1667165
52  2015-12-21 1092 0.1654236 0.1665495
53  2015-12-21 1113 0.1654459 0.1664299
54  2015-12-21 1134 0.1654673 0.1663000
55  2015-12-21 1155 0.1654879 0.1662152
56  2015-12-21 1176 0.1655079 0.1661180
57  2015-12-21 1197 0.1655271 0.1660165
58  2015-12-21 1218 0.1655456 0.1659519
59  2015-12-21 1239 0.1655636 0.1657849
60  2015-12-21 1260 0.1655809 0.1657073
61  2015-12-21 1281 0.1655976 0.1655520
62  2015-12-21 1302 0.1656139 0.1654799
63  2015-12-21 1323 0.1656296 0.1653000
64  2015-12-21 1344 0.1656448 0.1652425
65  2015-12-21 1365 0.1656595 0.1651239
66  2015-12-21 1386 0.1656738 0.1650000
67  2015-12-21 1407 0.1656877 0.1648901
68  2015-12-21 1428 0.1657012 0.1648000
69  2015-12-21 1449 0.1657142 0.1647000
70  2015-12-21 1470 0.1657269 0.1646000
71  2015-12-21 1491 0.1657393 0.1644705
72  2015-12-21 1512 0.1657513 0.1644032
73  2015-12-21 1533 0.1657630 0.1644480
74  2015-12-21 1554 0.1657743 0.1645000
75  2015-12-21 1575 0.1657854 0.1645000
76  2015-12-21 1596 0.1657961 0.1646000
77  2015-12-21 1617 0.1658066 0.1646399
78  2015-12-21 1638 0.1658168 0.1647000
79  2015-12-21 1659 0.1658268 0.1647000
80  2015-12-21 1680 0.1658365 0.1647549
81  2015-12-21 1701 0.1658460 0.1648000
82  2015-12-21 1722 0.1658552 0.1648000
83  2015-12-21 1743 0.1658642 0.1648368
84  2015-12-21 1764 0.1658730 0.1649000
85  2015-12-21 1785 0.1658816 0.1649000
86  2015-12-21 1806 0.1658900 0.1648442
87  2015-12-21 1827 0.1658982 0.1648000
88  2015-12-21 1848 0.1659062 0.1648000
89  2015-12-21 1869 0.1659140 0.1647316
90  2015-12-21 1890 0.1659217 0.1647000
91  2015-12-21 1911 0.1659292 0.1647000
92  2015-12-21 1932 0.1659365 0.1646602
93  2015-12-21 1953 0.1659437 0.1646000
94  2015-12-21 1974 0.1659507 0.1646000
95  2015-12-21 1995 0.1659576 0.1646000
96  2015-12-21 2016 0.1659643 0.1645899
97  2015-12-21 2037 0.1659709 0.1645198
98  2015-12-21 2058 0.1659773 0.1645000
99  2015-12-21 2079 0.1659837 0.1645000
100 2015-12-21 2100 0.1659899 0.1645000
101 2015-12-21 2121 0.1659959 0.1644496
102 2015-12-21 2142 0.1660019 0.1644000
103 2015-12-21 2163 0.1660077 0.1644000
104 2015-12-21 2184 0.1660134 0.1643750
105 2015-12-21 2205 0.1660191 0.1643380
106 2015-12-21 2226 0.1660246 0.1643017
107 2015-12-21 2247 0.1660300 0.1643000
108 2015-12-21 2268 0.1660353 0.1642968
109 2015-12-21 2289 0.1660405 0.1642309
110 2015-12-21 2310 0.1660456 0.1641806
111 2015-12-21 2331 0.1660506 0.1641442
112 2015-12-21 2352 0.1660556 0.1641084
113 2015-12-21 2373 0.1660604 0.1641000
114 2015-12-21 2394 0.1660652 0.1640847
115 2015-12-21 2415 0.1660699 0.1640210
116 2015-12-21 2436 0.1660745 0.1639732
117 2015-12-21 2457 0.1660790 0.1639335
118 2015-12-21 2478 0.1660834 0.1639000
119 2015-12-21 2499 0.1660878 0.1638653
120 2015-12-21 2520 0.1660921 0.1638000
121 2015-12-22   21 0.1431529 0.1426524
122 2015-12-22   42 0.1403679 0.1444571
123 2015-12-22   63 0.1467133 0.1466772
124 2015-12-22   84 0.1513388 0.1482843
125 2015-12-22  105 0.1543437 0.1504085
126 2015-12-22  126 0.1563804 0.1518340
127 2015-12-22  147 0.1578400 0.1536498
128 2015-12-22  168 0.1589353 0.1551931
129 2015-12-22  189 0.1597872 0.1562000
130 2015-12-22  210 0.1604689 0.1571264
131 2015-12-22  231 0.1610265 0.1580308
132 2015-12-22  252 0.1614913 0.1587339
133 2015-12-22  273 0.1618845 0.1598251
134 2015-12-22  294 0.1622215 0.1610027
135 2015-12-22  315 0.1625137 0.1619547
136 2015-12-22  336 0.1627693 0.1628018
137 2015-12-22  357 0.1629948 0.1636025
138 2015-12-22  378 0.1631953 0.1642695
139 2015-12-22  399 0.1633746 0.1647928
140 2015-12-22  420 0.1635361 0.1652014
141 2015-12-22  441 0.1636821 0.1656103
142 2015-12-22  462 0.1638149 0.1659284
143 2015-12-22  483 0.1639361 0.1662283
144 2015-12-22  504 0.1640473 0.1664581
145 2015-12-22  525 0.1641495 0.1666965
146 2015-12-22  546 0.1642439 0.1668902
147 2015-12-22  567 0.1643313 0.1670911
148 2015-12-22  588 0.1644124 0.1673821
149 2015-12-22  609 0.1644880 0.1676236
150 2015-12-22  630 0.1645585 0.1677935
151 2015-12-22  651 0.1646244 0.1678000
152 2015-12-22  672 0.1646863 0.1678000
153 2015-12-22  693 0.1647444 0.1678000
154 2015-12-22  714 0.1647990 0.1678000
155 2015-12-22  735 0.1648506 0.1678000
156 2015-12-22  756 0.1648993 0.1678000
157 2015-12-22  777 0.1649453 0.1677211
158 2015-12-22  798 0.1649890 0.1677000
159 2015-12-22  819 0.1650304 0.1676000
160 2015-12-22  840 0.1650697 0.1676000
161 2015-12-22  861 0.1651071 0.1675585
162 2015-12-22  882 0.1651427 0.1675000
163 2015-12-22  903 0.1651767 0.1673857
164 2015-12-22  924 0.1652091 0.1672494
165 2015-12-22  945 0.1652401 0.1672000
166 2015-12-22  966 0.1652697 0.1670559
167 2015-12-22  987 0.1652981 0.1670000
168 2015-12-22 1008 0.1653253 0.1669093
169 2015-12-22 1029 0.1653514 0.1668119
170 2015-12-22 1050 0.1653764 0.1667000
171 2015-12-22 1071 0.1654005 0.1666000
172 2015-12-22 1092 0.1654236 0.1664445
173 2015-12-22 1113 0.1654459 0.1663618
174 2015-12-22 1134 0.1654673 0.1662899
175 2015-12-22 1155 0.1654879 0.1661076
176 2015-12-22 1176 0.1655079 0.1660090
177 2015-12-22 1197 0.1655271 0.1660000
178 2015-12-22 1218 0.1655456 0.1658472
179 2015-12-22 1239 0.1655636 0.1657843
180 2015-12-22 1260 0.1655809 0.1657038
181 2015-12-22 1281 0.1655976 0.1656472
182 2015-12-22 1302 0.1656139 0.1656000
183 2015-12-22 1323 0.1656296 0.1655888
184 2015-12-22 1344 0.1656448 0.1655000
185 2015-12-22 1365 0.1656595 0.1654588
186 2015-12-22 1386 0.1656738 0.1654000
187 2015-12-22 1407 0.1656877 0.1654000
188 2015-12-22 1428 0.1657012 0.1653000
189 2015-12-22 1449 0.1657142 0.1653000
190 2015-12-22 1470 0.1657269 0.1652397
191 2015-12-22 1491 0.1657393 0.1652000
192 2015-12-22 1512 0.1657513 0.1652000
193 2015-12-22 1533 0.1657630 0.1651473
194 2015-12-22 1554 0.1657743 0.1651000
195 2015-12-22 1575 0.1657854 0.1651000
196 2015-12-22 1596 0.1657961 0.1650366
197 2015-12-22 1617 0.1658066 0.1650000
198 2015-12-22 1638 0.1658168 0.1650000
199 2015-12-22 1659 0.1658268 0.1649378
200 2015-12-22 1680 0.1658365 0.1649000
201 2015-12-22 1701 0.1658460 0.1649000
202 2015-12-22 1722 0.1658552 0.1648397
203 2015-12-22 1743 0.1658642 0.1648000
204 2015-12-22 1764 0.1658730 0.1648000
205 2015-12-22 1785 0.1658816 0.1647451
206 2015-12-22 1806 0.1658900 0.1647000
207 2015-12-22 1827 0.1658982 0.1646888
208 2015-12-22 1848 0.1659062 0.1646000
209 2015-12-22 1869 0.1659140 0.1646000
210 2015-12-22 1890 0.1659217 0.1645000
211 2015-12-22 1911 0.1659292 0.1645000
212 2015-12-22 1932 0.1659365 0.1644572
213 2015-12-22 1953 0.1659437 0.1644000
214 2015-12-22 1974 0.1659507 0.1644000
215 2015-12-22 1995 0.1659576 0.1643545
216 2015-12-22 2016 0.1659643 0.1643000
217 2015-12-22 2037 0.1659709 0.1643000
218 2015-12-22 2058 0.1659773 0.1643395
219 2015-12-22 2079 0.1659837 0.1643904
220 2015-12-22 2100 0.1659899 0.1644000
221 2015-12-22 2121 0.1659959 0.1644000
222 2015-12-22 2142 0.1660019 0.1644000
223 2015-12-22 2163 0.1660077 0.1644000
224 2015-12-22 2184 0.1660134 0.1644268
225 2015-12-22 2205 0.1660191 0.1644638
226 2015-12-22 2226 0.1660246 0.1645000
227 2015-12-22 2247 0.1660300 0.1645000
228 2015-12-22 2268 0.1660353 0.1644937
229 2015-12-22 2289 0.1660405 0.1644278
230 2015-12-22 2310 0.1660456 0.1643789
231 2015-12-22 2331 0.1660506 0.1643425
232 2015-12-22 2352 0.1660556 0.1643067
233 2015-12-22 2373 0.1660604 0.1643000
234 2015-12-22 2394 0.1660652 0.1642816
235 2015-12-22 2415 0.1660699 0.1642180
236 2015-12-22 2436 0.1660745 0.1641718
237 2015-12-22 2457 0.1660790 0.1641328
238 2015-12-22 2478 0.1660834 0.1641000
239 2015-12-22 2499 0.1660878 0.1640622
240 2015-12-22 2520 0.1660921 0.1640000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neste caso você pode incluir mais um elemento ao seu gráfico especificando que a variável `ind` vai gerar diferentes facetas, isto é, `facet_wrap(~ind)`:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df$m, y=df$X2, colour=ind))+ 
  xlab('m') + ylab('Taxas')+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position='top') +
  ggtitle('.')+ 
  geom_point()+ geom_line()+
  geom_point(aes(x=df$m,y = df$X1,colour=ind)) +
  geom_point(y = df$X1, color="black")+
  geom_line(y = df$X1, color="blue")+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12,colour="black"),axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45)) +
  facet_wrap(~ind)
```